# Как лучше реализовать if-else выражение в Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, if, thymeleaf

Каким способом лучше всего реализовать выражение `if-else` в Thymeleaf?

Мне хотелось бы добиться в Thymeleaf того же, что я делаю в нижеприведенном примере на JSTL.

**Пример с использованием JSTL:**

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${potentially_complex_expression}">
     <h2>Hello!</h2>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
     <span class="xxx">Something else</span>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Что мне на данный момент удалось сделать в Thymeleaf:

```
<div th:with="condition=${potentially_complex_expression}" th:remove="tag">
    <h2 th:if="${condition}">Hello!</h2>
    <span th:unless="${condition}" class="xxx">Something else</span>
</div>
```

**НО** я не хочу **дважды вычислять** `potentially_complex_expression`.
Поэтому мне приходится вводить локальную переменную `condition`.
И все равно мне не очень по душе обращаться постоянно к этому выражению в обоих случаях:

- `th:if="${condition}`
- `th:unless="${condition}"`.

Также стоит отметить, что я использую два разных тега HTML: `H2` и `SPAN` - это важно!

**Существует ли более корректный способ сделать тоже самое?**

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494078/how-to-do-if-else-in-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В
Thymeleaf есть аналоги `<c:choose>` и `<c:when>`:
это атрибуты `th:switch` и `th:case` введенные в  Thymeleaf 2.0.

**Пример:**

```
<div th:switch="${user.role}"> 
  <p th:case="'admin'">Пользователь является администратором</p>
  <p th:case="#{roles.manager}">Пользователь является менеджером</p>
  <p th:case="*">Пользователь имеет какую-то другую роль</p> 
</div>
```

Данная структура работает похоже аналогичному выражению `switch` в Java.
Выражение указанное в `th:switch` вычисляется и сравнивается с результатами вычислений внутри `th:case`
При этом атрибутом `th:case="*"` помечается случай, который долже выбираться по умолчанию(*если никакой другой кейс не подходит*).

[Здесь](https://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew20.html#swit) можно чуть подробнее узнать об этом синтаксисе (*или в [туториалах Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements)*).

---

**Ссылки:**

- Описание синтаксиса `th:switch` в changelog'e Thymeleaf
  https://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew20.html#swit
- Описание синтаксиса в туториалах Thymeleaf
  https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13601710/4558866